# Batch file running ant build.xml unknown target

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, batch-file, ant

I'm using a batch file to run the ant build.xml.
But it always shows unknown target, yet build successful.
How can I edit the build.xml so that the batch file can find the target in the build.xml?

I'm using ant to automate the transformation of the project in pure::variants

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test01" default="ff">
   <target name="ff">
      <pv.import path="C:\Users\Z0091673\pure-variants-workspace-4.0\Test01"/>
      <pv.transform name="Default" vdm="C:/Users/Z0091673/pure-variants-workspace-4.0/Test01/Config/VariantModel.vdm"/>
      <eclipse.refreshLocal resource="Test01"/>
   </target>
</project>
```

Comment: `eclipse.refreshLocal` only works when the build.xml is run by Eclipse using 'run in the same JRE as the workspace'

Comment: yes that is correct. The software pure::variants provides users with eclipse editor and jre as workspave. I solved this problem by updating pure::variants. This ant build file has nothing wrong but the version of the software, or we say the batch file that runs ant build.xml. Thank you for giving me ideas and have a good day.